# How to plot a sawtooth chirp waveform using an array of frequency and time for an FMCW radar?

Tags: python, signal-processing

Before switching to use sawtooth I was using sine wave but in sine wave high frequency content was not clearly visible, But I don't have any experience with using sawtooth waveforms. I am going to make a custom block from this code in GNU Radio so I won't be able to use scipy.signal.sawtooth or signal.chirp. as some libraries don't work in GNU radio.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import pi

chirp_duration = 60e-6
f0 = 1e6 
f1 = 3e6 
no_samp = 1001
rcs = 0.0377

f_step = (f1-f0)/no_samp
rf_axis = np.linspace(f0, f1, int(f_step))
rt_axis = np.linspace(0, chirp_duration, int(f_step))

# rchirp = np.cos(2 * np.pi * rf_axis * rt_axis)

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 3))
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.title('Received Chirp')
plt.plot(rt_axis, rf_axis)
plt.show()
```

This is the code I was using to generate the chirp signal in sine wave. This code works perfectly for low frequency values of f0 and f1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SciPy to generate a sawtooth signal   https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.sawtooth.html

This is their provided example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(0, 1, 500)
plt.plot(t, signal.sawtooth(2 * np.pi * 5 * t))
plt.show()
```

**UPDATED**
Thinking about this more, I don't think you're actually after a sawtooth signal. You just want a repeating chirp signal which produces a sawtooth pattern in the frequency domain. See if this helps:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## Make a single chirp signal
t_chirp = np.linspace(0, 2, 500)
w_chirp = signal.chirp(t_chirp, f0=1, f1=6, t1=2, method='linear')
fs = 1/(2/500)

## Repeating the chirp signal 5 times
num_repeats = 5
t = np.linspace(0, 2*num_repeats, 500*num_repeats)
w = np.copy(w_chirp)
for i in range(num_repeats-1):
    w = np.hstack((w, w_chirp))

## Finding the instantaneous frequency
analytic_signal = signal.hilbert(w)
instantaneous_phase = np.unwrap(np.angle(analytic_signal))
instantaneous_frequency = (np.diff(instantaneous_phase) / (2.0*np.pi) * fs)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(10,4))
ax[0].plot(t, w)
ax[0].set_title("Linear Chirp")
ax[0].set_xlabel('t (sec)')

ax[1].plot(t[:-1], instantaneous_frequency)
ax[1].set_title("Instantaneous Frequency")
ax[1].set_xlabel('t (sec)')
ax[1].set_ylabel("Frequency (Hz)")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Actually I am going to make a custom block from this code in GNU Radio so I won't be able to use scipy.signal.sawtooth or signal.chirp. as some libraries don't work in GNU radio.  Thanks for the quick answer though.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your chirp function might be incorrect.

Checking the instantaneous frequency of your time-domain chirp signal, it would seem that the frequency of your signal increases twice as fast as it should.

[This site](https://www.gaussianwaves.com/2014/07/chirp-signal-frequency-sweeping-fft-and-power-spectral-density-matlab-python/) gives a slightly different formula for producing a chirp. It is originally for MATLAB, but we can easily translate it to Python :

```py
def linear_chirp(t: np.ndarray, f0, f1, p, phase_offset=0):
    '''
    make a linear chirp

    Arguments:
     * t            : array of sample times
     * f0           : starting frequency 
     * f1           : end frenquency
     * p            : chirp period
     * phase_offset : initial phase offset
    '''
    return np.cos(2*np.pi*((f1-f0)/p/2*t + f0)*t + phase_offset)
```

The following function, based on the method given by astroChance in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76764715/21688300), can be used to check the instantaneuous frequency :

```py
def ifreq(t: np.ndarray, x: np.ndarray):
    '''
    find the instantaneous frequency of a singal
    Arguments:
     * t    : array of evenly spaced sample times
     * x    : signal samples at sample times `t` 
    '''
    # import scipy.signal because this is only for testing purposes
    # it is not necessary for the final version
    from scipy.signal import hilbert

    fs = len(t)/t.ptp()  # evenly spaced samples !!!
    analytic_signal = hilbert(x)
    instantaneous_phase = np.unwrap(np.angle(analytic_signal))
    return (np.diff(instantaneous_phase) / (2.0*np.pi) * fs)
```

To illustrate all of this :

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

chirp_duration = 60e-6
f0 = 1e6 
f1 = 3e6 
no_samp = 1001

f_step = (f1-f0)/no_samp
rf_axis = np.linspace(f0, f1, int(f_step))
rt_axis = np.linspace(0, chirp_duration, int(f_step))

rchirp = np.cos(2 * np.pi * rf_axis * rt_axis)

***
define linear_chirp and ifreq here
***

mychrip = linear_chirp(rt_axis, f0, f1, chirp_duration, 0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(10, 4))
ax[0].plot(rt_axis, rchirp, 'b')
ax[0].plot(rt_axis, mychrip, 'r')
ax[0].set_title("Linear Chirp")
ax[0].set_xlabel('t (sec)')

ax[1].plot(rt_axis[:-1], ifreq(rt_axis, rchirp), 'b')
ax[1].plot(rt_axis[:-1], ifreq(rt_axis, mychrip), 'r')
ax[1].plot(rt_axis, rf_axis, 'k--')
ax[1].set_title("Instantaneous Frequency")
ax[1].set_xlabel('t (sec)')
ax[1].set_ylabel("Frequency (Hz)")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This gives us the following output, where we can see that the frequency of your original method starts out correctly, and then grows about twice as fast as it should:
[image]

That being said, it looks like there might also be some confusion in the generation of your `rf_axis` and your `rt_axis`. I think you might have meant to use `np.arange` instead of `np.linspace` for the frequency generation. Something like the following would make more sense with the variable names you chose :

```py
f_step = (f1-f0)/no_samp
rf_axis = np.arange(f0, f1, f_step)
rt_axis = np.linspace(0, chirp_duration, len(rf_axis))
```

By playing around with this, you'll find that you're getting quite close [frequency folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency) with your current values, which will result in some aliasing.

Anyhoo, hope all this helps, at least a bit.